# Find all the starting alphabets in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

How to find all the starting alphabets in a table row name.

```
names
allan
brain
chris
chap
charlie
rosy
ram
dude

output
a
b
c
r
d
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the builtin `SUBSTRING` function and the `DISTINCT` to return different results (*no duplicates*)

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(SUBSTRING(names, 1,1)) x
FROM t
ORDER BY x;
```

**[MySQL: SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)**

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f0e30/7)

Comment: i get both lower case and upper case as different  like alphin Alan output as a A

Comment: so you mean lowercase `a` is different from uppercase `A`?

Comment: i meant it should only display the name starting with a or A as A particular

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f0e30/2  i need for postgresql

Comment: perfect one... but what does LOWER function do?!!!

Comment: it changes the case of the letter. from uppercase to lower case :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(LEFT(names,1)) tt
FROM myTable
ORDER BY tt;
```

OR you can also do the same with [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(SUBSTRING(names, 1,1)) tt
FROM myTable
ORDER BY tt;
```

## [*See this Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/84bd0/7)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f0e30/2 i need for postgresql

Comment: @dude Are you trying this with PostgreSQL or MySQL?
Your demo is in PostgreSQL.

Comment: yup @hims056!!! m trying in postgre

Comment: @dude See the updated answer and fiddle.